# How can I access a RIR's (regional internet registry) database?

Tags: c#

I wish to access a RIR's (regional internet registry) database, and extract information about a particular IP address. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know if the provider has an API, for example, RIPE has [this](http://labs.ripe.net/ripe-database/database-api/api-introduction) which should allow for what you want. Failing that, the only other way would be to scrape the website for the information required - something that may not be allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You can access IP address information by querying an RIR's WHOIS server, or by searching their web interface. Each RIR should have a search form on the home page.

Each RIR also has a public FTP with a plethora of information, including IP data in CSV.

RIR FTP servers:

> ARIN - ftp.arin.net
>
> RIPE NCC - ftp.ripe.net
>
> APNIC - ftp.apnic.net
>
> LACNIC - ftp.lacnic.net
>
> AfriNIC - ftp.afrinic.net